# Grasp simulation tool

Tags: grasp, motion-planning

I want to do some grasp motion planning experiments, but I failed with compiling the *GraspIt!* using VS2010 on Win7. Is there has other grasp simulation tool like GraspIt! that can be used in Win7 and VS2010 environment? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had been trying to install Graspit for Windows 7 too, but failed somehow and then switched to OpenRAVE. OpenRAVE is open source and provides an environment for testing, developing, and deploying motion planning algorithms in real-world robotics applications. The installation guide for Windows can be found [here](http://openrave.org/docs/latest_stable/coreapihtml/index.html). There are a lot of quick start examples, which cover topics to help you get started with Inverse kinematics, testing a grasp, implementing planners and controllers. You could also work in a MATLAB, Octave or Python interface.

You can also find lots of relevant information on the [OpenRAVE user mailing list](http://openrave-users-list.185357.n3.nabble.com/), or ask questions when you need help.

I am running OpenRAVE on Ubuntu 12.04 though, and the installation was fairly easy.